# How to pass a custom query to the sfPager for getting pagination?

Tags: php, symfony1, pagination, symfony-1.4, propel

Below is the sql query. Here 3 tables are used. `EMPLOYER`, `COMPANYPROFILE`,`JOBSEEKERFOLLOWER`

```
$c=new Criteria();
$c->add(EmployerPeer::ITEMPLOYERSTATUS, 1);
$c->addJoin(EmployerPeer::IDEMPLOYER, CompanyprofilePeer::IDEMPLOYER);
EmployerPeer::addSelectColumns($c);
$c->addJoin(EmployerPeer::IDEMPLOYER, JobseekerfollowingPeer::IDEMPLOYER);
JobseekerfollowingPeer::addSelectColumns($c);
$c->addAsColumn('count', 'COUNT(EMPLOYER.IDEMPLOYER)');
$c->addGroupByColumn(CompanyprofilePeer::VCCOMPANYNAME);

//echo $c->toString(); exit;

$pager = new sfPropelPager('Employer', E4sConfig::getRecordsPerPage());
$pager->setCriteria($c);
$pager->setPage($this->getRequestParameter('page', 1));
$pager->init();
$this->pager=$pager;
```

If I remove the exit and print the SQL query and if I run it, it is getting perfectly.

Now, I need to pass it to pager for pagination. But issue with this is, if `Employer` class is used while creating a new object for `sfPropelPager` it results only the elements of that class. I don't get any details of other two tables/ classes (company profile and jobseekerfollower). It happens same if used with either of the tables.

What I exactly want is - just to execute the query. How can this be achieved? Please let me know few good examples where joins and custom queries are used with sfPropel object.

Thanks

Comment: Which Propel version are you using ? Btw I didn't understand your problem :-/

Comment: hi @j0k: I am getting the below query if I uncomment toString() function - `SELECT 
EMPLOYER.IDEMPLOYER, EMPLOYER.VCCOMPANYNAME, EMPLOYER....., 
JOBSEEKERFOLLOWING.IDJOBSEEKERFOLLOWING, JOBSEEKERFOLLOWING.IDJOBSEEKER, JOBSEEKERFOLLOWING.IDEMPLOYER, COUNT(EMPLOYER.IDEMPLOYER) AS count 
FROM 
EMPLOYER, JOBSEEKERFOLLOWING, COMPANYPROFILE 
WHERE EMPLOYER.ITEMPLOYERSTATUS=1 AND COMPANYPROFILE.ITSTATUS=1 AND EMPLOYER.IDEMPLOYER=COMPANYPROFILE.IDEMPLOYER AND EMPLOYER.IDEMPLOYER=JOBSEEKERFOLLOWING.IDEMPLOYER 

GROUP BY COMPANYPROFILE.VCCOMPANYNAME ORDER BY EMPLOYER.IDEMPLOYER ASC`

Comment: If I pass `$pager = new sfPropelPager('Employer', ` Employer class, it is returning employer object `array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(Employer)#135 (86) {
    ["idemployer:protected"]=>
    int(1)`.... So I want to get the query result in pagination.

Comment: And you want the pager to return which kind of object? And which propel version are you using?

Comment: Hi @j0k: I am using propel V 1.2 and I just want to get the result of the query on `Success` page (`$pager`). If I pass `$pager = new sfPropelPager('Employer'`, I get employer object in result. But I want a object which will have all the result of specified query.

Comment: Yep it returns an `Employer` object, but do you have a `Companyprofile` & `Jobseekerfollowing` attached as a relation? I mean, did you try to retrieve these value ?

Comment: @j0k: `Employer` and `Companyprofile` is in relation. `Jobseekerfollowing` is independent. Do you know how to get this query into the pager? Thanks

Comment: But do you have a *real* relation inside your model between `Employer` & `Jobseekerfollowing` ?

Comment: No @j0k ... there is NO relation between `Employer` and `Jobseekerfollowing`. But `Employer` and `Companyprofile` are related. In `BaseEmployer.php` I can see  `initCompanyprofiles()` method

Comment: I don't know how Propel can handle a relation that doesn't not exists in its model. You should try this Criteria alone (without the pager) and this if you can retrieve `Jobseekerfollowing` information. But, why they don't have a relation since they both have a `idemployer`?